# Method chaining in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, chaining

I did not understand the following code snippet from "Programming Principles and Practice" 2nd ed. by Bjarne Stroustroup article 13.3.

```
void Lines::draw_lines() const
{
    if (color().visibility())
    for (int i=1; i<number_of_points(); i+=2)
        fl_line(point(i–1).x,point(i–1).y,point(i).x,point(i).y);
}
```

I did not understand the color().visibility() part. What actually is this? I heard about method chaining though I am not fully understand this. Is this an example of such method chaining? I have seen in the wikipedia that, in a chained method the first function should return an object and the second function becomes the member function of that returned object by the first function. However, here in this example by Bjarne Stroustroup there is no instance before the color() function. How will this color() become a member function for an object as there is no instance to work on? Can anybody enlighten on this please?

Comment: There is an instance. The one that `draw_lines()` method was called on.

Comment: `in a chained method the first function should return an object` A _reference_ to an object, rather.

Comment: @dxiv: Not necessarily. `auto obj = createObject().makeObjectRed().makeObjectGreat()` -- all of these may return by value, and the first one probably _must_.

Comment: @PreferenceBean Technically correct, though practically it would be odd for any but the first call to construct a new object.

Comment: @dxiv: It would. But, then, it was the first object that was being talked about in your comment.

Comment: @PreferenceBean In the given code, it looks to me more likely that `color()` is an accessor function for some `_color` member, rather than a function that returns a copy thereof, or a new object altogether.

Comment: @dxiv: Agreed. Again, though, that's not what you were replying to. Never mind.

Answer (score 4):

> there is no instance before the color() function

It doesn't matter. `color()` might be a member function of `Lines` (with instance `this`), or a global free function (without instance at all).

And then as you said, the second function `visibility()` supposed to be the member function of that returned object by the first function `color()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this an example of such method chaining?

Typically, method chaining describes chained calls to member functions, which return the instance (by reference) on which they're called. But in this case, the first function appears to not be a member function of the instance that it returns. Otherwise the pattern is identical to method chaining.

> However, here in this example by Bjarne Stroustroup there is no instance before the color() function.

And thus you can deduce that `color` is either a non-member function, or a member of `Lines` in which case the instance is implicitly `this`. You can also deduce that it returns an instance to an object that does have a member function `visibility`. Of course, you don't need to do such deduction if you have the declaration of `color` available.

> How will this color() become a member function for an object as there is no instance to work on?

It does not *become a member function*. If it's a member function of `Lines`, then it works on `this`, otherwise it is a free function and does not need an instance. In either case, it can return an unrelated instance of some type that has a member function by the name of `visibility`.